# jQuery:Element Selection based on multiple attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following HTML

```
<tr id="r1" class="l1">
                <td><img class="plusminus" id="r1c1" src="assets/images/plus.png" border="0" />3/10/12</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>4,449,371</td>
                <td>27,399</td>
                <td>$500,000</td>
                <td>8.91%</td>
                <td>0.68%</td>
                <td>0.62%</td>
                <td>$0.04</td>
                <td>791</td>
                <td>2.8%</td>
                <td>$1.39</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="r11" class="l2">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>iPad Winner</td>
                <td>700,302</td>
                <td>2,472</td>
                <td>98.88</td>
                <td>8.07%</td>
                <td>0.68%</td>
                <td>0.62%</td>
                <td>$0.04</td>
                <td>791</td>
                <td>2.8%</td>
                <td>$1.39</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="r12" class="l2">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>iPad Winner2</td>
                <td>300,302</td>
                <td>2,472</td>
                <td>98.88</td>
                <td>8.07%</td>
                <td>0.68%</td>
                <td>0.62%</td>
                <td>$0.04</td>
                <td>791</td>
                <td>2.8%</td>
                <td>$1.39</td>
            </tr>

      <tr id="r2" class="l1">
                <td><img class="plusminus"  id="r2c1" src="assets/images/plus.png" border="0" />4/10/12</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>4,4555,55</td>
                <td>27,399</td>
                <td>$500,000</td>
                <td>8.91%</td>
                <td>0.68%</td>
                <td>0.62%</td>
                <td>$0.04</td>
                <td>791</td>
                <td>2.8%</td>
                <td>$1.39</td>
            </tr>

<tr id="r21" class="l2">
                <td><img class="plusminus"  id="r2c1" src="assets/images/plus.png" border="0" />4/10/12</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>4,4555,55</td>
                <td>27,399</td>
                <td>$500,000</td>
                <td>8.91%</td>
                <td>0.68%</td>
                <td>0.62%</td>
                <td>$0.04</td>
                <td>791</td>
                <td>2.8%</td>
                <td>$1.39</td>
            </tr>
```

Here **r1** is a Parent Row while **r11**,**r12** are child rows, parent has class li while children has l2. I am using following jQuery on click event of id=r1 where all subsquent Ids being with r1 and have class l2

```
var pattern = 'r1';//just for example here
$('tr[id|="'+pattern+'"][class=l2]')
```

I need a filtered result based on **id matches pattern AND have class = l2**. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks ok to me. Do you have any problem with it? You might want to put `l2` in quotation marks as well. Or better yet, just use the class selector: `$('tr.l2[...]')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**
This should do the trick:

```
var pattern = 'r1';//just for example here
$('tr[id^="'+pattern+'"][class=l2]')
```

Your selector does not work because you are using '|=' which matches a prefix followed by '-'. so if your naming convention for child rows was r1-1, r1-2 that selector would have been good. You need to use '^=' which selects attributes starting with a specified string.

Personally I would, instead of having ids on child rows, simply specify a parent id as a class on child rows - this makes things a bit simpler so all children of id=r1 would look like this

```
<tr id="r1" class="l1"><td>I am a parent row</td></tr>
<tr class="l2 r1"><td>I am a child row of r1</td></tr>
```

so to select child rows when a user clicks a parent row I would do this

```
$(".l1").click(function(){
var sel = $(this).attr("id");
var children = $("table").find("." + sel)

})
```

but this is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I ended up assinging multiple classes on each level like **l2 r1** for first row, **l2 r2** to second, so on and then call class based selector. I really liked your implementation. Will be helpful in future

Answer (score 0):

```
$('id|=["' + pattern + '"] > .l2')
```

Which means: give me all children with class *.l2* of a parent with id prefixed with *pattern*

Edit: Sorry, noticed you were looking for prefix, updated code.